# Google Play and OpenSSL warning message Smartface Application

Tags: smartface.io

I just received an email from Google play stating:

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> Your app(s) listed at the end of this email utilize a version of OpenSSL that >contains one or more security vulnerabilities. If you have more than 20 >affected apps in your account, please check the Developer Console for a full >list.
>
> Please migrate your app(s) to OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r or higher as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK. Beginning July 11, 2016, Google Play will block publishing of any new apps or updates that use older versions of OpenSSL. If you’re using a 3rd party library that bundles OpenSSL, you’ll need to upgrade it to a version that bundles OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r or higher.
>
> The vulnerabilities were addressed in OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r. The latest versions of OpenSSL can be downloaded here. To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep search for ($ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL").
>
> To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version to the Developer Console and check back after five hours. If the app hasn’t been correctly upgraded, we will display a warning.
>
> The vulnerabilities include "logjam" and CVE-2015-3194. The Logjam attack allows a man-in-the-middle attacker to downgrade vulnerable TLS connections to 512-bit export-grade cryptography. This allows the attacker to read and modify any data passed over the connection. Details about other vulnerabilities are available here. For other technical questions, you can post to Stack Overflow and use the tags “android-security” and “OpenSSL.”
>
> While these specific issues may not affect every app that uses OpenSSL, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Apps with vulnerabilities that expose users to risk of compromise may be considered in violation of our Malicious Behavior policy and section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.
>
> Apps must also comply with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Developer Program Policies. If you feel we have sent this warning in error, contact our policy support team through the Google Play Developer Help Center.
>
> Regards,
>
> The Google Play Team

Guide me out of this if smatface app studio needs to be updated or not. Do let me know when will the update come.